# Blurry avatars on HiDPI displays

Tags: bug, design

In order to make images rendered naturally on HiDPI monitors, image size must be larger than parent element.
Otherwise browser has to upscale images, and they become blurry.
This rule is ignored in some of the places.
This affects both gravatars and uploaded avatars:

- question/answer author -- blurry (32x32 image in 32x32 box)
- /review -- blurry (32x32 image in 32x32 box)
- user's own avatar in top header -- perfect (48x48 image in 24x24 box)

Sensitivity to visual quality varies from person to person, so it is even possible
that developers simply do not realize that something is wrong.
But we, who are oversensitive to visual quality, notice this immediately and our eyes become sore.

I believe that this bug is browser-agnostic, but anyway, here is my system info:

- User-agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
- Native resolution: 2880x1800

Comment: *our eyes become sore* You like to exaggerate a tiny bit?

Comment: Not at all, @rene. Some things may be really annoying (and, by the way, easily fixed).

Comment: Yeah, some things can be really annoying ...

Comment: I disagree with the "sore eyes" bit, but this seems like something that's easy enough to fix. +1