# Facebook avatars are displayed in HiDPI/Retina, but other avatars are not

Tags: bug, design, gravatar, facebook

Users that log in through Facebook get to have the avatars in their signature blocks displayed in HiDPI/Retina: they have 200x200 pixels of image data displayed in 32x32 logical/CSS pixels (6.25x). A little excessive, but these look great on all devices!

However, avatars which come from any other source (Gravatar, Imgur, Google+) are only displayed with 32x32 pixels of image data (1x). This is below the 2x-3x physical/logical pixel ratio used by many devices, [causing them to appear blurry for many users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339327/blurry-avatars-on-hidpi-displays).

Compare:

> [image]

Consider making avatar resolutions consistent, regardless of their source.

Comment: I propose we lower Facebook users' resolutions to 1x1.

Comment: What is "HiDPI"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I am probably misusing the term, but I'm using it to mean "an image which contains at least 2 pixels of image data for each 'logical pixel' in each CSS dimension". So if we're displaying an image at 32x32 logical/CSS pixels, "HiDPI" image data would have at least 64x64 pixels (2x), so that it would appear crisp on a display that has 2x physical pixels for each logical pixel (most smartphones, many laptops). This is what Apple calls "retina-quality".

Comment: Somehow related (it was also asking for consistency: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259904/avatar-facebook). We, using default Firefox's content-blocking come to see a [0x0 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z582y.png) for gravatars, since our browser [considers it a tracker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGKla.png).

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384864/stack-overflow-lets-facebook-track-me-across-their-sites)